# Comparing structs in Go

Tags: go, struct, equality, platform

I have a test that compares the equality of two pointers to instances of a struct (`MyStruct`). The pointers are stored within other structs (`container1` and `container2`). Here's how I check the equality:

`require.Equal(*container1.MyStruct, *container2.MyStruct)`

the `Equals()` method is from the Testify library: https://github.com/stretchr/testify/blob/master/require/require_forward.go#L128

This test passes when I run it on my Mac. However, when I push my changes to our build server (Linux), the test fails. The error message is the standard `Error: Not equal...` message, but when I diff the expected and actual shown in the output, they're exactly the same!

I thought maybe Go is somehow comparing the addresses of the pointers rather than the contents, but the comment on require.Equal makes this seem unlikely:

`// Pointer variable equality is determined based on the equality of the referenced values (as opposed to the memory addresses)`

Any idea what's going on here? Does Go behave differently on Mac vs Linux?

I'm not able to post specifics here as it's an issue I'm seeing in a codebase I touch at work.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're running the exact same versions of Go in both environments? Have you tried using reflect.DeepEqual or assert.Equal? It might also be a dependency issue (your IDE may be referencing a local version of stretchr/require different that the one being obtained in your build server)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant source code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @A.Lorefice `require.Equal` and `assert.Equal` are using `reflect.DeepEqual` in their implementation as I remember. The only problem is when you try to compare struct which contains maps because they do not keep order. But it should work otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there's a bug in the output of the `Equal` function's "expected... actual..." printing logic for structs when the struct contains a `Time` object. Here's a snippet from the error output: (I've removed the irrelevant fields of the struct):

```
        Error Trace:    my_test.go:388
                                    my_test.go:50
        Error:          Not equal:
                        expected: {
                          BuildStartDateUtc: 2020-08-17 22:43:05.330062876 +0000 UTC,
                          

                        actual  : {
                          BuildStartDateUtc: 2020-08-17 22:43:05.330062876 +0000 UTC,                            
                        }
```

Fields look the same. However, if I compare `MyStruct.BuildStartDateUtc` directly, I get this:

```
expected: &time.Time{wall:0x389ccfe6, ext:63733398658, loc:(*time.Location)(0x101d4e0)}
actual : &time.Time{wall:0x389ccfe6, ext:63733398658, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}
```

The "loc" field is missing in the actual. This is what's causing the comparision to fail, but since "loc" evidently is not included in the output when we compare a struct that contains a `Time`, we get a very confusing "expected... actual..." output where the actual/expected look exactly equal when they're not.

When I syncronized the `Location` of the `Time`s being compared the test passed.

Looks like it might be related to this Testify issue: https://github.com/stretchr/testify/issues/984